# SkypeBot on botframework

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, bots, skype, skypedeveloper

I have a task to create a Skype bot. Maybe I am not entirely in the right place, but I will write here anyway. I registered the bot at this address "https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new". During the bot's creation, I also created an application in Azure at "https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade". I obtained the necessary credentials and completed the bot registration. I am receiving callbacks from the bot on my server, which is working fine. Next, according to the documentation, I am preparing to set up the bot's logic on the server. I decided to start with sending a message, using the documentation from "https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#reply-to-activity". I managed to obtain the token successfully, but I am unable to send a message. I receive a 401 response with the message "Authorization has been denied for this request." I don't understand what the problem is. I read in the documentation that it is possible the bot has not passed the authentication check. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

I hope to get some guidance on whether I am looking at the documentation correctly and to receive some suggestions on what I might be doing wrong and where to pay attention